# Entity Framework Database Agnostic Development

Tags: mysql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity

I want to use the Entity Framework in my application. I understand that I can use the Entity Framework with MySQL. I am familiar with SQL Server and very happy with using its tools. However with my web host I have to use MySQL. Is it possible to develop locally using SQL Server and then deploy the solution to MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just install MySql locally and dev/test against that?

Failing that, you can switch out the provider at deployment easily enough as it's part of the connection string.  However, you'll need to do some reading to understand the differences in Provider support for your LINQ queries as you may find yourself using something supported by the SQL Server provider that doesn't work as well or at all against the MySQL provider.